# android softkeyboard to not cover any part of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am using a `ScrollView` as the parent in my layout file. In my manifest, for the activity, I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. But the problem is that although the focus is not covered by the keyboard, part of the EditText is covered. This makes it difficult to move around in the multiline EditText.

As use case

Say I am four lines in, and I want to go back to line 2 to edit a misspelling. When I try to move the cursor, the EditText jumps up and down, making the user experience crappy. So how do I get the entire EditView to appear above the keyboard? And yes, there is room for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your ScrollView: `android:isScrollContainer="false"`

See also [Forcing adjustPan in activity containing ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114993/forcing-adjustpan-in-activity-containing-scrollview) for reference.